# OS X: dylib rpath wrong after compiling

Tags: dylib, rpath, otool

I'm building cyrus sasl2 libraries from source. The libs get installed in /usr/local/lib, and the headers in /usr/local/include/sasl, which is proper.

However, when I run apps that try to use them, I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /libsasl2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/sbin/postdrop
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Running otool -L on the lib shows a bad relative path:

```
libsasl2.dylib:
  /libsasl2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
  /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

How can I change the way make compiles the library so that the correct rpath is encoded?
I read about install_name_tool to change it in the library, but that doesn't seem to work using '-change' since the correct path, '/usr/local/lib/libsasl2.dylib', is longer than the currently encoded one. Shouldn't I be able to set that at the time I build the library somehow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`install_name_tool -id "@rpath/libsasl2.dylib" "/usr/local/lib/libsasl2.dylib"` would change `LC_ID_DYLIB` of the `libsasl2.dylib`. When postdrop links to it, that would be added to `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` of postdrop. Then you can add an `LC_RPATH` entry of `/usr/local/lib` to postdrop and everything would work.